# Python extracting substrings within brackets in a string

Tags: python, split, string-matching

I am looking for a way to extract substrings from a string if it precedes a certain identifier.

```
string = [food(type, description), newCar(make, year), fruit(shape, colour), usedCar(make, year), ..., identifier(str1, str2)]
identifier = car (newCar and/or usedCar) - extract if both appear or either one appear

Desired outcome

identifier: newCar
first attribute = make
second attribue = year

identifier: usedCar
first attribute = make
second attribue = year
```

This is what I tried but I seem to be getting only the first occurrence of the (..). Any ideas to fix this and it would be better if I could get the individual strings inside the bracket as well?

```
sent = '[food(type, description, newCar(make, year), fruit(shape, colour), usedCar(make, year), ..., identifier(str1, str2)]'

id1 = 'newCar'
id2 = 'usedCar'

if id1 in sent:
    carDesc1= sent.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
    print carDesc1

    if id2 in sent:
        carDesc2= sent.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
        print carDesc2

Print results: 
type, description
type, description
```

EDIT: 
Thank you for the response. One of the reasons I didn't consider Dict is because the key must be unique and I have a text with multiple lines and there might be duplicate newCar entries within the same line. And the text inside the brackets are only generic terms as it could indicate make = Toyota/Ford or year = 2010/2013.

Answer (score 0):

```
params = sent.split(id1)[1].split(")")[0].lstrip("(")
print params
```

That should do what you want.  That being said, there are better ways to do this.  You could store your items as key:value pairs using a dictionary for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression:

```
import re

escaped_identifiers = [re.escape(id) for id in ('newCar', 'usedCar')]
regex = re.compile(r'({})\(([^)]*)\)'.format('|'.join(escaped_identifiers)))
for type, params in regex.findall(the_text):
    make, year = params.split(',')
```

If you already know that the identifier will have a `make,year` pair you can extract them too:

```
import re

escaped_identifiers = [re.escape(id) for id in ('newCar', 'usedCar')]
regex = re.compile(r'({})\(([^,]*),([^)]*)\)'.format('|'.join(escaped_identifiers)))
for type, make, year in regex.findall(the_text):
    # process a match.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitively not the best solution but it works.

```
string = '[food(type, description), newCar(make, year), fruit(shape, colour), usedCar(make, year)]'
# Strip the brackets from the string
string = string.strip('[]')

# Create a dict with identifiers and attributes 
id_attr = dict([i.split('(') for i in string.split('), ')])

# Clean up the attributes and make a list of them
for identifier, attributes in id_attr.items():
    id_attr[identifier] = attributes.strip(')').split(', ')

for i, attrs in id_attr.items():
    # Print the identifier
    print('identifier: {i}'.format(i=i))
    # Print each attribute, numbered
    for num, a in enumerate(attrs):
        print('attribute {num}: {a}'.format(num=num, a=a))
    print('')  # Print empty line
```

If you want to lookup attributes using the identifiers you can use the dict.